# Update Sharepoint 2007 MySites layout and web parts for already deployed MySites

Tags: deployment, my-site

We are looking to change our users' MySite home pages to make them more useful.  I can find information on how to update the MySite template used to deploy new MySites, but I need to make the changes to 800 sites that have already been created.  I am not having much luck finding details on how to do this.

I am working with Office Sharepoint Server 2007 sp2.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add/change some webparts you could use something like this:

```
foreach (SPWebApplication webapp in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications) {
    foreach (SPSite site in webapp.Sites) {
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        if(web.WebTemplate == "yourmysitetemplate") {
            //do something with webparts
            using(SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared)) {
                foreach(AspNetWebpart webpart in manager.WebParts) {
                    using(webpart) {
                        if(webpart is SomeWebPart) {
                            SomeWebPart swp = (SomeWebPart)webpart;
                            swp.SomeProperty = "somevalue";
                            manager.SaveChanges(webpart);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```